# Calling functions changes weird values

Tags: c++

Basically, whenever I call certain functions it ends up changing other values that are unrelated to what I did.

I have defined

```
typedef struct {

double x;
double y;
} coordinate;

class collisionBox {

public:
double x, y, lineOfSight, length, width;
int index, angle;

coordinate cornerPosition (int number); //corners go clockwise from top
coordinate position (void);
coordinate lineOfSightLocation (void);
collisionBox (void);
};
```

The problem arises in this function:

```
aCollision collisionImminent (collisionBox object)
{

coordinate corners[3], lOS;
aCollision result;

int n = 0;

while (n <= boxIndex) {

    if (n != object.index) {


        corners[0] = allBoxes[n]->cornerPosition(1);
        corners[1] = allBoxes[n]->cornerPosition(2);
        corners[2] = allBoxes[n]->cornerPosition(3);
        corners[3] = allBoxes[n]->cornerPosition(4);

        cout << "corners[3].y = " << corners[3].y << "\n";

        lOS = object.lineOfSightLocation();

        cout << "corners[3].y = " << corners[3].y << "\n";
```

The value of corners[3].y changes after I call object.lineOfSightLocation() (it changes to the y value of lOS), I can't figure out why...

Here's the other function:

```
coordinate collisionBox::lineOfSightLocation (void)
{

coordinate lOS;

lOS.x = x + cos(angle * RADIANS) * lineOfSight;
lOS.y = y + sin(angle * RADIANS) * lineOfSight;

return lOS;
}
```

Anyways, thanks for your time and help, I'm probably doing something utterly wrong, but I really have no idea what it is...

Answer (score 6):

You got lucky, actually.

If you look at:

```
coordinate corners[3], lOS;
```

You have **3** corners, then `lOS` *should* come immediately after in memory.

Later, you refer to:

```
    corners[3] = allBoxes[n]->cornerPosition(4);
```

The **fourth** corner in the array, which doesn't exist. You're writing past the end of the array, which is undefined, but because of how the variable are laid out in memory, it writes into `lOS` instead of crashing your computer/imploding the world/causing all spacetime to cease existing.

Thus, when you read from (the non-existant) `corners[3]`, you're reading from `lOS`, which you just set.

You simply need to change the declaration to `coordinate corners[4]` and you'll be good. :)

Comment: Spacetime did cease existing, but only temporarily, for 0 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

You declared corners as:

```
coordinate corners[3]
```

This means that there are three elements: corners[0], corners[1], and corners[2]. Yet you refer to a corners[3], which is out-of-bounds. In this case, you are corrupting the stack by modifying it.

You need to declare your object as `corners[4]` to be able to reference corners[3]. I should add that you have a bit of repetitive code there that you could get rid of with a for loop. That would also make it less likely that you would refer to a non-existent array element (if you are consistently using a length variable, rather than some fixed constant that needs to be kept consistent in multiple places).

Answer (score 1):

corners[3] is having its values changed because corners[3] doesn't really exist.

Arrays in c++ are 0-based. This means that when you declare

```
coordinate corners[3]
```

You DO get 3 coordinates...but they are located at corners[0], corners[1], and corners[2]. Corners[3] is actually past the end of the array. By coincidence, since you declared los directly after the corners array, changes to it happen to be observable as changes to coordinates[3]. Such behavior is not defined and should certainly not be depended upon.

Switch your definition of coordinates[3] to coordinates[4]... or better yet, since this is C++, use a [vector](http://cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/).